# JFileChoser to select multiple files in the order they were selected

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want JFileChoser to select multiple files and get the list of selected files in the order they were selected.
is it possible?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: The first part, yes, the second part, not so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes technically this is possible with a `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`.

```
final JFileChooser diag = new JFileChooser();
diag.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

final List<File> chosen = new ArrayList<File>();

diag.addPropertyChangeListener(
                    JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILES_CHANGED_PROPERTY,
                    new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {

        List<File> selected = Arrays.asList(diag.getSelectedFiles());
        Iterator<File> it = chosen.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
            if (!selected.contains(it.next()))
                it.remove();

        for (File file : selected)
            if (!chosen.contains(file))
                chosen.add(file);
    }
});

if (diag.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // 'chosen' holds selected files in order of selection
```

Not elegant and I don't know how stable this is.

Comment: +1 working well. Can you please explain where and how is the effective part of the code that performs the ordering instructions?.